How does the often used picture about Lebesgue integration relate to the actual definition
Often when comparing Riemann and Lebesgue integration pictures like the following are used (credits to this Reddit post by user u/Analemmath)

However the actual most common definition of Lebesgue integration uses simple function and a picture of it would look more like

I must say the first picture makes somewhat sense with the definition of measurable function. A measurable function $f: \Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ between the measure space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ with its Borel sigma-algebra is just a function for which the preimage of open sets is measurable. So it makes sense for example to consider a partition $y_k$ of the codomain into intervals $[y_k, y_{k+1}]$ and consider the sums
\begin{equation}
\sum_k (y_{k+1} - y_k)\mu(f^{-1}([y_k, y_{k+1}]))
\end{equation}
and the measurability condition is what grants that $f^{-1}([y_k, y_{k+1}])$ is measurable (since it is the complement of an open set, which is measurable in the Borel sigma-algebra). This sums are basically what is being considered in the first image with the partition being a partition into intervals of equal width.
Ultimately what is the relation between the two pictures?
